# Getting python file to return different values based on the input arguments using argparse

Tags: python, return-value, argparse

Let's say I have a function `f1()`

```
def f1(input1, input2):
     # does some magic
     return p1, p2

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Help function description')
    parser.add_argument('t1', help='Token')
    parser.add_argument('t2', help='Another token')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    p1, p2 = f1(args.t1, args.t2)
```

Let's say this file is called street.py. I want to use the same file to return p1 when the argument arg1 is an input and p2 when argument arg2 is an input.
Outside the file :

```
variable1 = (python3 ../street.py t1 t2 -arg1)
variable2 = (python3 ../street.py t1 t2 -arg2)
```

I'm a bit confused over the argparse argument style from the documentation, what's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using:

```
parser.add_argument('-arg1', '--argument1', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

this will store `True` in the variable `args.argument1` if you call `python3 ../street.py t1 t2 -arg1`, so that you can later use a simple if/elif statement to separate the different cases, i.e.:

```
if args.argument1 is True:
    print(p1)
```

Comment: Actually `if args.argument1:` is sufficient and also better, sorry for the error.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Make the call in the terminal like this (linux)

```
variable=$(python3 streep.py t1 'foo' t2 'bar')
```

you should associate each param `t1` and `t2` with their respective values.
Also only return a single value from `f1` which you will `print` to `stdout`

---

You should consider what you want the behaviour to be. If you want to use the output of `f1` then be explicit in its arguments what is mandatory and what is an optional input.
Also consider what you want the output to be, since this is a script passing values will be through `stdout` you kinda only have the one line to `print`.

```
def f1(input1, input2):
     # does some magic
     return p1 or p2
```

Then simply print the result to stdout with python `print()` statement

An example based on your code could look like

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import sys
def f1(input1, input2):
     # does some magic
    return input1 or input2

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Help function description')
    parser.add_argument('--t1', help='Token')
    parser.add_argument('--t2', help='Another token')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    try:
        result = f1(args.t1, args.t2)
        print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=sys.stderr)
        exit(1)
```

I can then use this script as

```
variable=$(python3 streep.py --t2 'bar')
```

Comment: you could also have `p1 or p2` at the end of `f1`

Answer (score 0):

With this file:

```
import argparse, sys

def f1(input1, input2):
     # does some magic
     print('inside f1')
     return input1, input2

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(sys.argv)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Help function description')
    parser.add_argument('t1', help='Token')
    parser.add_argument('t2', help='Another token')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    
    p1, p2 = f1(args.t1, args.t2)
    print(p1, p2)
```

Asking for help (in a shell window):

```
201:~/mypy$ python3 stack64684099.py -h foo bar
['stack64684099.py', '-h', 'foo', 'bar']
usage: stack64684099.py [-h] t1 t2

Help function description

positional arguments:
  t1          Token
  t2          Another token

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

running with 2 arguments as specified in the help:

```
1201:~/mypy$ python3 stack64684099.py foo bar
['stack64684099.py', 'foo', 'bar']
Namespace(t1='foo', t2='bar')
inside f1
foo bar
```

I added prints to show `sys.argv` the list of strings that argparse gets from the shell.  And the `namespace` that parsing produced, and the results of running `f1`.

===

I don't know where you are doing:

```
variable1 = (python3 ../street.py t1 t2 -arg1)
variable2 = (python3 ../street.py t1 t2 -arg2)
```

There's nothing in your `parser` set up that looks for or pays attention to those '-arg1','-arg2' strings.  And what they are supposed to do is not clear in your question.

I could redirect `stdout` to file:

```
1202:~/mypy$ python3 stack64684099.py foo bar > test.txt
1208:~/mypy$ cat test.txt
['stack64684099.py', 'foo', 'bar']
Namespace(t1='foo', t2='bar')
inside f1
foo bar
```

Omitting all but the last print give just the `foo bar` line.

The primary purpose of the `parser` is to read and understand/parse the user input.  If you are happy with the results in the `args` namespace, the rest is up to your own code.  As defined your arguments are simple strings, which you can use as is or test for certain values.  You can also produce numbers, and with the correct `action`, boolean values.  You can also define `optionals`, arguments that expect a `flag` string like `--arg1`.